# In BlueJ, how do I correctly call variables created in one constructor to a constructor in another class?

Tags: java, bluej

I have this code:

```
public class Address
{
// instance variables 
private String postcode;
private String street;
private String town;


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Address
 */
public Address(String street, String town, String postcode)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    this.street = street;
    this.town = town;
    this.postcode = postcode;
}



public String getPostcode()
{
    return postcode;
}

public String getStreet()
{
    return street;
}

public String getTown()
{
    return town;
}

public void printAddress()
{
    System.out.println(street);
    System.out.println(town);
    System.out.println(postcode);
}

public void setFullAddress(String street, String town, String postcode)
{
   this.street = street;
   this.town = town;
   this.postcode = postcode;
}

public void setPostcode(String postcode)
{
    this.postcode = postcode;
}

public void setStreet(String street)
{
    this.street = street;
}
```

I need to call the variables postcode, town and street in the constructor in another class which is:

```
 private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String libraryNumber;
private int noOfBooks;
private Address address;


/**
 * this constructor creates a borrower and sets the number of books on loan to one.
 * 
 * @param in order for the borrower to be created the fName, lName and lNumber must be provided
 */
public Borrower(String fName ,String lName ,String lNumber, String town, String street, String postcode)
{
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    libraryNumber = lNumber;
    noOfBooks = 1; 
}
```

I have tried doing this in a few ways however have not found a way to call them correctly so when the object borrower is created it grabs the postcode, town and street from the address class. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pass in an address to the constructor and set the instance field `address` equal to it. Using the get methods, you can access all its variables...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
address.setFullAddress(street,town,postcode);
```

After that you can use get methods of `address` class wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to call the constructor directly with the object of the class `Address`:

```
public Borrower(String fName ,String lName ,String lNumber, Address addr)
{
 ...
    address = addr; 
}
```

Other way would be to create the object in constructor:

```
public Borrower(String fName ,String lName ,String lNumber, String town, String street, String postcode)
{
...
    address = new Address(town, street, postcode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the construtor of the 2nd class just pass a reference of the Address class.

```
Public Borrower(Address address){
this.address=address;
}
```

now add the getter method of Address and then u can access all the instance variables of the Address class.